# Why is the exponential map defined as the integral curve evaluated at 1?

Tags: differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* he states:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we define a map $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G$, called the **exponential map of $G$**, as follows: for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, we set $$\exp X = \gamma(1),$$ where $\gamma$ is the one-parameter subgroup generated by $X$, or equivalently the integral curve of $X$ starting at the identity.

Why do we define $\exp X$ as $\gamma(1)$? What is special about the value of $\gamma$ at $1$?

Comment: Nothing is special at the $1$. We could define $\exp X$ to be $\gamma(14)$ and nothing significant would change — you'd end up with some constants at some points (for example, the differential of $\exp$ would not be the identity but $14$ times the identity)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez As a follow up question, why are we defining the exponential to be the integral curve evaluated at some constant in the first place? I think I am missing the bigger picture here.

Comment: We are not defining the exponential as that: the exponential *is* that. The exponential of, say, matrix groups is something that exists independently of Lie theory. Definitions do not create things: they give names to things that exist. Think of the case of $GL(n,R)$: the exponential is just the exponential, the usual power series. How would you explain to someone what that is, though, without a lot of complication? Well, people, after a century or so, have come to the conclusion that describing that map in terms of, say, integral curves is particularly efficient.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see, so if we apply the usual power series of the exponential we get $\gamma(1)$ for any integral curve $\gamma$?

Comment: How do you define the exponetial function — the *original* exponential function that maps a real number $t$ to $e^t$. There are many ways to do it, some more complicated, some more technical, some more elementary — they are all equivalent, of course, of when you have to give a definition it is good to pick one that makes things easy for you. In the case of the good ol' exponential a good way is to say that it is the unique function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1$. This is entirely analogue to the definition of the abstract $\exp$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah I think I understand now. Thank you for all your help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The usual power series does not make any sense at all if what you have is a Lie group and its Lie algebra. One needs a description of the exponential of matrix groups (where we do have the power series formula) in terms that make sense in any Lie group — the definition you mentioned in the question has this property.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez After thinking about it some more I realized I did not understand it as well as I had thought. Why are we interested in the differential equation $f' = f$ for Lie algebras?

Comment: We are not. It does not even make sense. What I wrote is that the exponential function of real numbers satisfies that differential equation, and it happens (this is something we learn from experience) that using that differential equation to define it is useful and convenient.

Comment: I honestly think that you should stop worrying about why we define things in the way we do, and why we are interested in the things in which we are interested, and the rest of the meta-questions you are trudging thru, and concentrate on learning the actual things.

Comment: D'Alambert used to tell his students "Allez en avant, et la foi vous viendra" (which means something like "keep going and faith will come") when they *doubted* calculus. It applies equally well to Lie theory.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you, I will take your advice and not look too much into it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that we want to travel in the direction of $x$ for a single unit of time to see where it takes us.

Think about the simplest example where $G$ is the multiplicative group of positive reals and $\mathfrak g$ is the additive reals.

Like most things in mathematics, the definition is usually motivated by its properties. In particular here, the $1$ is nice since it effectively causes the differential of this map to just be the identity. In other words, if we think as Lie algebras as the behavior of the group near the identity, then the 1 cancels out so the exponential map acts as the identity near 1.

Then if you choose some positive real $x$, this defines some curve (i.e. one parameter subgroup of G) with initial velocity $x$ as $\gamma(t)=e^{tx}$. This gives that $\exp x= \gamma(1)=e^x$. In other words, the exponential map of the the Lie group of the multiplicative reals matches our standard exponential function.

One possible objection is that if you’re familiar with physics dimensional analysis, then it feels a little weird to have something happen at 1 second because we might change our unit of time which could change the definition. However, we’ve defined the velocity of this path as $x$ distance per 1 “second”, so the velocity and the time cancel out when computing your location after that unit of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a little confused. So the map is defined that way to match the regular exponential function? If so, as a follow up I would ask what is so special about the exponential function in the context of Lie theory?

Comment: The reason the exponential function is useful in Lie theory is because it’s the unique solution to the analogue of $d/dt (e^{tx})=xe^{tx}$. The exponential function is what happens when you keep doing the small difference implied by $x$ starting at the identity for some fixed amount of time.

Comment: Sorry for yet another follow up question, but why is that idea/differential-equation of interest in Lie theory?

Comment: Err, not sure what background you’re coming from - but the entire point of Lie algebras is to study the infinitesimal structure of the Lie group. In order to go back and forth between talking about the derivative (lie group -> Lie algebra), you also need to be able to take an integral (Lie algebra -> Lie group). That’s what the exponential map is, effectively the integral of the Lie algebra, in a loose sense.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped and I think I understand now.